# Linux - Get Outbound/Inbound Traffic by IP address

Tags: linux, debian, bandwidth, router, dmz

I am hosting a website and I found that the traffic on my server is quite high.

My Linux server is behind a router in a DMZ. I would like to see the traffic made on my Linux box on the eth0 interface, based on the public IP address of the client.

I would then like to see which client is stealing my bandwidth.

Or is it better if I do it from my router with DD-WRT?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you just need a simple curses-based interface, [iptraf](http://iptraf.seul.org/) might be what you need. It shows you what connections are currently going on.

[image: iptraf screenshot]
<sub>(source: [seul.org](http://iptraf.seul.org/shots/iptraf-iptm1.gif))</sub>

However, if you need something more sophisticated, you could use the [ipt_netflow](https://sourceforge.net/projects/ipt-netflow/) Netfilter-target, which will send all the accounting-data to a Netflow-target.

P.S.: The [OpenWRT website](https://oldwiki.archive.openwrt.org/doc/howto/bwmon) gives more pointers about bandwidth-monitoring.

Answer (score 0):

Most DDWRT builds come with an application called RFlow. This application logs the traffic inbound and/or outbound in the router itself, together with the IPAddress, Port and the number of octets.

The data is collected in a database in the network (preferably internal). You could filter out the relevant data from this DB and analyze it.

I think RFlow is a port of the Cisco NetFlow protocol. So there should be a plethora of application floating around, which will help you analyze the data.